# Android developing an app

Tags: android

Is there any Android tutorial which is more than just a "Hello World!" or "Click me!"? I have googled it and most tutorials I found were with more than half of it on setting up SDK etc and then a little explanation on how to display hello world etc. I'd like to follow on to a bit more advanced tutorial before I can start creating my own test applications.

I'd like to develop an app (quiz game) as my test app having features list below -

- Display 10 questions with multiple choice answers. The question set gets updated every Monday.
- Keep a leaderboard of the highest scores with their time taken.

**PLEASE NOTE:** I am not expecting you to write code for me. I just made above app features list just to learn developing Android app as Hello World tutorial aren't good enough. If you know any tutorial which cover anything part related or even not... that'd be great.

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: I already looked - did you look at there "Building your first app" section ... there is nothing there other than what i said above...

Comment: How about all the other sections? Are they too easy for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend going to these sites to learn android:

http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6

http://www.vogella.com/android.html

http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

and since android is mostly java you should learn java with these sites:

http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=31

http://www.javavideotutorials.org/

http://www.javavideotutes.com/

and for the specifics of a quiz app go to these sites:

**Displaying Question**

http://android-helper.blogspot.ca/2011/07/simple-textview-source-code-main.html

**Getting user input**

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/

**Saving data**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

**Getting questions from server**

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1521

Answer (score 0):

Check out the thenewboston channel on Youtube. I've gone through the tutorial series and it's great so far. Here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC2F07DBCDCC01493A. Just skip to the more advanced tutorial videos. They're titled based on what they cover so it should be fairly straightforward. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of excellent tutorials on many different topics out there if you know where to look or rather what keywords to search.

You want questions with multiple choice, without anything more than that to go by lets say you have a screen with a question and some radio button options for the options or check boxes if there are more than one correct answer.

So now we have more granular requirements

1. A question, let's use a TextView for that, any Hello World tutorial will do for that and it seems you've already found one of those, great lets move on then.
2. Radio button choices - google "android radio button example" - first result [a Radio Button example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/)
3. Check boxes - google "android checkbox example" - first result [a Checkbox example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/)

What I'm trying to say here is, you need to define the requirements better then searching  for examples may be a better approach than trying to find a single place to learn everything...

... having said that Lars Vogel's site [vogella.com android tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/android.html) is very good resource and the 2 examples above are from the same site so you might want take a look there [mykong.com android tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/android-tutorial/)

Comment: thx let me have a look ... i m newbie so abit lost